# When querying XML in SQL Server 2005, multiple tags of the document are in the same row

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2005, xquery-sql

**Update to provide clarification**

Here's a full copy of one of the xml files I"m having trouble with.

```
<Grower_Run xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Puller xsi:type="Puller">
    <Puller_Number xsi:type="xsd:int">16</Puller_Number>
  </Puller>
  <Run_ID xsi:type="xsd:string">SA1611030B</Run_ID>
  <Crucible xsi:type="Crucible">
    <Crucible_Type xsi:type="xsd:string">RWNTYPE</Crucible_Type>
    <Section>
      <Grower_Run_Section>
        <SectionID xsi:type="xsd:string">SA1611030B1</SectionID>
        <Crystal_Growth>
          <Growth_StartTime xsi:type="xsd:dateTime">2011-03-01T12:59:30</Growth_StartTime>
          <Growth_Process>
            <Growth_Process>
              <Process_Name xsi:type="xsd:string">BODY</Process_Name>
              <Single_Moment_Snapshot>
                <Single_Moment_Snapshot>
                  <Snapshot_Name xsi:type="xsd:string">Body Start</Snapshot_Name>
                  <Snapshot_Datetime xsi:type="xsd:dateTime">2011-03-01T17:11:30</Snapshot_Datetime>
                  <Ingot_Length xsi:type="xsd:decimal">228.19</Ingot_Length>
                  <Heater_Temp xsi:type="xsd:decimal">1337.09</Heater_Temp>
                  <LS_Temp xsi:type="xsd:decimal">1243.00</LS_Temp>
                  <Heater_Power xsi:type="xsd:decimal">56.10</Heater_Power>
                </Single_Moment_Snapshot>
                <Single_Moment_Snapshot>
                  <Snapshot_Name xsi:type="xsd:string">Mid Body</Snapshot_Name>
                  <Snapshot_Datetime xsi:type="xsd:dateTime">2011-03-01T17:11:30</Snapshot_Datetime>
                  <Ingot_Length xsi:type="xsd:decimal">228.19</Ingot_Length>
                  <Heater_Temp xsi:type="xsd:decimal">1337.09</Heater_Temp>
                  <LS_Temp xsi:type="xsd:decimal">1243.00</LS_Temp>
                  <Heater_Power xsi:type="xsd:decimal">56.10</Heater_Power>
                </Single_Moment_Snapshot>
                <Single_Moment_Snapshot>
                  <Snapshot_Name xsi:type="xsd:string">Tail Start</Snapshot_Name>
                  <Snapshot_Datetime xsi:type="xsd:dateTime">2011-03-02T01:34:24</Snapshot_Datetime>
                  <Ingot_Length xsi:type="xsd:decimal">230.40</Ingot_Length>
                  <Heater_Temp xsi:type="xsd:decimal">1338.20</Heater_Temp>
                  <LS_Temp xsi:type="xsd:decimal">1243.40</LS_Temp>
                  <Heater_Power xsi:type="xsd:decimal">56.39</Heater_Power>
                </Single_Moment_Snapshot>
              </Single_Moment_Snapshot>
            </Growth_Process>
          </Growth_Process>
          <Growth_FinishTime xsi:type="xsd:dateTime">2011-03-02T01:35:24</Growth_FinishTime>
        </Crystal_Growth>
      </Grower_Run_Section>
      <Grower_Run_Section>
        <SectionID xsi:type="xsd:string">SA1611030B9</SectionID>
        <Crystal_Growth>
          <Growth_StartTime xsi:type="xsd:dateTime">2011-03-02T04:02:37</Growth_StartTime>
          <Growth_Process>
            <Growth_Process>
              <Process_Name xsi:type="xsd:string">BODY</Process_Name>
              <Single_Moment_Snapshot>
                <Single_Moment_Snapshot>
                  <Snapshot_Name xsi:type="xsd:string">Body Start</Snapshot_Name>
                  <Snapshot_Datetime xsi:type="xsd:dateTime">2011-03-02T07:54:39</Snapshot_Datetime>
                  <Ingot_Length xsi:type="xsd:decimal">231.80</Ingot_Length>
                  <Heater_Temp xsi:type="xsd:decimal">1340.00</Heater_Temp>
                  <LS_Temp xsi:type="xsd:decimal">1246.70</LS_Temp>
                  <Heater_Power xsi:type="xsd:decimal">56.60</Heater_Power>
                </Single_Moment_Snapshot>
                <Single_Moment_Snapshot>
                  <Snapshot_Name xsi:type="xsd:string">Mid Body</Snapshot_Name>
                  <Snapshot_Datetime xsi:type="xsd:dateTime">2011-03-02T07:54:39</Snapshot_Datetime>
                  <Ingot_Length xsi:type="xsd:decimal">231.80</Ingot_Length>
                  <Heater_Temp xsi:type="xsd:decimal">1340.00</Heater_Temp>
                  <LS_Temp xsi:type="xsd:decimal">1246.70</LS_Temp>
                  <Heater_Power xsi:type="xsd:decimal">56.60</Heater_Power>
                </Single_Moment_Snapshot>
                <Single_Moment_Snapshot>
                  <Snapshot_Name xsi:type="xsd:string">Tail Start</Snapshot_Name>
                  <Snapshot_Datetime xsi:type="xsd:dateTime">2011-03-03T06:47:19</Snapshot_Datetime>
                  <Ingot_Length xsi:type="xsd:decimal">1778.00</Ingot_Length>
                  <Heater_Temp xsi:type="xsd:decimal">1388.80</Heater_Temp>
                  <LS_Temp xsi:type="xsd:decimal">1330.70</LS_Temp>
                  <Heater_Power xsi:type="xsd:decimal">63.50</Heater_Power>
                </Single_Moment_Snapshot>
              </Single_Moment_Snapshot>
            </Growth_Process>
          </Growth_Process>
          <Growth_FinishTime xsi:type="xsd:dateTime">2011-03-03T06:48:19</Growth_FinishTime>
        </Crystal_Growth>
      </Grower_Run_Section>
    </Section>
  </Crucible>
</Grower_Run>
```

Ok so for clarification here is my full query.

```
DECLARE @FILES TABLE(FILENAME VARCHAR(20),DEPTH INT,FILE_FLAG INT)
DECLARE @XML_TABLE TABLE(
    xmlFileName VARCHAR(300),
    xml_data xml
)
DECLARE @xmlFileName VARCHAR(300)
DECLARE @FILENAME VARCHAR(20)

INSERT INTO @FILES
EXEC Master.dbo.xp_DirTree '\\SASSOAPPSRV\Grower XML Files\',1,1

DECLARE XML_CURSOR CURSOR FOR SELECT FILENAME FROM @FILES

OPEN XML_CURSOR
FETCH NEXT FROM XML_CURSOR 
INTO @FILENAME

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

SELECT  @xmlFileName = '\\SASSOAPPSRV\Grower XML Files\' + @FILENAME

INSERT INTO @XML_TABLE(xmlFileName, xml_data)
EXEC('
SELECT ''' + @xmlFileName + ''', xmlData 
FROM
(
    SELECT  * 
    FROM    OPENROWSET (BULK ''' + @xmlFileName + ''' , SINGLE_BLOB) AS XMLDATA
) AS FileImport (XMLDATA)
')
FETCH NEXT FROM XML_CURSOR 
INTO @FILENAME

END
CLOSE XML_CURSOR
DEALLOCATE XML_CURSOR

DECLARE @PARSED_XML TABLE(
S VARCHAR(200),
RUN_ID VARCHAR(20)
,SECTION_ID VARCHAR(50)
)



INSERT INTO @PARSED_XML
SELECT 
T.xmlFileName AS S,
    t.xml_data.value('(/Grower_Run/Run_ID)[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS 'RunID',
    Section.value('(Grower_Run_Section/SectionID)[1]', 'varchar(50)') as 'SectionID'
FROM
    @xml_table t
CROSS APPLY
    t.xml_data.nodes('/Grower_Run/Crucible/Section') AS Tmp(Section)

SELECT 
S
,RUN_ID
,SECTION_ID
 FROM @PARSED_XML
WHERE RUN_ID = 'SA1611030B'
 ORDER BY RUN_ID
```

And this is the result I'm getting.

```
\\SASSOAPPSRV\Grower XML Files\SA1611030B.xml   SA1611030B  SA1611030B1
```

This is the issue since I need to see data from both copies of the  node in separate rows.

---

So I have many XML documents with the following structure

```
<Grower_Run xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Run_ID xsi:type="xsd:string">SA0111023B</Run_ID>
  <Crucible xsi:type="Crucible">
    <Section>
      <Grower_Run_Section>
        <SectionID xsi:type="xsd:string">SA0111023B1</SectionID>
      </Grower_Run_Section>
    </Section>
    <Section>
      <Grower_Run_Section>
        <SectionID xsi:type="xsd:string">SA0111023B9</SectionID>
      </Grower_Run_Section>
    </Section>
  </Crucible>
</Grower_Run>
```

That I've imported into an XML field of a temp table which I'm querying against with a query like this one

```
SELECT
   CAST(XML_DATA.query('data(/Grower_Run/Run_ID)') AS VARCHAR(20)) AS [RUN ID]
  ,CAST(XML_DATA.query('data(/Grower_Run/Crucible/Section/Grower_Run_Section/SectionID)') AS VARCHAR(50)) AS [SECTION ID]
FROM @XML_TABLE
```

So the problem is that my results from the multiple instances of the "SectionID" tag are showing up in the same row.

i.e.

```
   RunID    |   SectionID
--------------------------
SA0111023B  |    SA0111023B1  SA0111023B9
```

when it should be

```
RunID       |   SectionID
-----------------------------
SA0111023B  |    SA0111023B1  
SA0111023B  |    SA0111023B9
```

If I had [1] to then end of the xml query like this

```
CAST(XML_DATA.query('data(/Grower_Run/Crucible/Section/Grower_Run_Section/SectionID)')[1]
```

it will drop the second section ID all together which doesn't work cuz I need both.

Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to select out multiple "rows" from a XML document, you need to use the `.nodes()` SQL Server XML function - something like this:

```
SELECT 
    @XMLTable.value('(/Grower_Run/Run_ID)[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS 'RunID',
    Section.value('(Grower_Run_Section/SectionID)[1]', 'varchar(50)') as 'SectionID'
FROM
    @XMLTable.nodes('/Grower_Run/Crucible/Section') AS Tmp(Section)
```

That XPath statement in the `FROM` clause basically defines a "pseudo-table" of XML elements - based on that XPath. So here you get a pseudo-table for each `<Section>` entry in your XML - from which you can then select individual elements using the `.value()` function.

If you want to select that from a table that contains a column of type `XML`, you might need to check into the `CROSS APPLY` command:

```
SELECT 
    t.SomeColumn,        
    t.XmlColumn.value('(/Grower_Run/Run_ID)[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS 'RunID',
    Section.value('(Grower_Run_Section/SectionID)[1]', 'varchar(50)') as 'SectionID'
FROM
    dbo.YourTable t
CROSS APPLY
    t.XmlColumn.nodes('/Grower_Run/Crucible/Section') AS Tmp(Section)
```

Comment: I see the idea of what your suggesting here but I'm having trouble implementing it. Trying to apply the top suggestion I'm getting an error: Must declare the scalar variable "@XML_TABLE". I'm loading my xml into a column of a table variable and then running these queryies off of that it it matters.

Comment: @Neberu: the first approach would be valid is you had your XML in a SQL variable. If you have a table, you need to use the second approach

Comment: Thank you, I tried the second approach and it is querying without errors but it appears to only be returning the first instance of the nodes, just like putting [1] at the end of the query mentioned at the end of my question above.

Comment: @neberu: I'm pretty sure it works just fine - I use it all the time. And I tried it on your sample data provided - I got the output you expected. You must be doing something else wrong..... can you post your query you're using? Or ask a new question?

Comment: Ok so I updated my question with full copies of what I'm using.

Comment: @neberu: okay, so **which** nodes would you like to enumerate?? There **IS** only a single `/Grower_Run/Crucible/Section` in your sample XML - so you get only a single row as a result - works as designed... (but probably not as you intended it to work..()

Comment: *Ding*, you just helped me get it. I just had move Grower_Run_Section down to the pseudo table declaration since it's that node that I need to enumerate.

Comment: @marc_s: `.nodes()` is not an XQuery function, but a not SQL standard and SQL-Server specific function.

Comment: @marc_s: +1 By the way. You know your SQL-Server!

Answer (score 1):

this will work..., for example:

```
pref.value('(OriginatorAgency/text())[1]','varchar(50)'),
pref.value('(OriginatorAgency/text())[2]','varchar(50)'),
pref.value('(OriginatorAgency/text())[3]','varchar(50)')
```

If there are 3 OriginatorAgency items.